# Mvc :Not being redirected to Proper view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, razor

As a beginner i am doing very simple  MVC program , in  this program user fills a form and those values are  received in  ThankYou page(view) .

MY model class

```
 namespace MvcPro1.Models
{
    public class GuestResponse
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public bool? willattend { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is code for form in my `Default1Controller`

```
[HttpGet]    
 public ViewResult RSVPForm()
        {
            return View(); 
        }
```

when i right click and goto its view that is  `RSVPForm.cshtml`

```
<div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        { 
            <p>Your Name @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Name)</p>

            <p>Your Email @Html.TextBoxFor(y => y.Email)</p>
            <p>Your Phone @Html.TextBoxFor(z=>z.Phone) </p>

            <p>Will You attend ?</p>

            @Html.DropDownListFor(a=>a.willattend  , new []
            { 
                 new SelectListItem () {Text="Yes i willb be there ", Value= bool.TrueString }, 
                 new SelectListItem () {Text= "No i will not be ther ", Value  = bool.FalseString} , 

            },  "Choose an option "); 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" />
        }
    </div>
```

as you can see Its strongly typed view .  now to  `get these values in my controller class` i have

```
[HttpPost]
        public ViewResult RSVPForm(GuestResponse guest)
        {
            return View("ThankYou", guest);  
        }
```

and here is its `view` `ThankYour.cshtml`

```
    <div>

        Thank you @Model.Name . 
        if(@Model.willattend==true)
          Its great to listen you are coming , Drinkis are already in Fridge . 
        else 
           Sorry to hear you  cant come to attent 

    </div>
```

problem is that when i press submit button that does not take me to thankyou page , instead it gives 404 and when i  try to go to thank you page via controller goto view (right click) that also takes me to my form view not Thankyou that i added for this , will someone help me with this whats wrong with  this code  . Thank you

Comment: `ThankYour.cshtml` may be *your* problem. Rename it to `ThankYou.cshtml`.

Comment: You may have a problem with that ThankYou.chtml view anyway. I don't think you can use `if..else..` shortcuts like that in Razor. You have to `@if (condition) { ... } else { ... }`. It can be on multiple lines, but it needs the opening and closing brackets. Also the text inside the brackets needs to be wrapped in an HTML element like `<p>Sorry to hear...</p>`

Comment: @JeremyCook yes that was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you said your view is called ThankYour.cshtml but your returning  ThankYou could that be the problem

Comment: @Sikander ah, it's frustrating no doubt but I wouldn't be too hard on yourself. It happens to most of us.

Comment: and finally my first MVC code is working perfectly :D